# Shadows in pin annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, shadow

Why when I load my **pin annotation** in **map**, my pin annotations have different number **shadow**? Some have no shadows and some have many shadows.

I receive the data for pin from the **firebase**.

How to remove shadow or how to make a small shadow in all pin?

Check image

[image]

Comment: Are there many pins on the same location? This will create a darker shadow.,

Comment: one of the addresses that has the thick shadow has 2 pin, but shadow is big or one of the addresses have 10 pin, but his shadow is small

Comment: It seems that you many *multiple* pin at the same exact location, that's why the pin shadows are not the same for all pins (locations).

Comment: How about using MKAnnotationView custom Image(red pin) instead of MKPinAnnotationView?

Comment: I understand what the problem, each pin have many element. It's my wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

The darker shadow means you have *multiple pins in the same location*. There are two main causes for this and depending on the reason, there are two ways to solve this:

#### 1. The data contains multiple elements with the same location.

Consider using clustering, which will display the number of annotations in the location. This will be a lot easier for the user to understand than a darker shadow. :)

Here's a tutorial from Apple: [Decluttering a Map with MapKit Annotation Clustering](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering)

#### 2. You forgot to erase the annotations before adding them again.

Remove the annotations before adding them to the map again, for example when you're refreshing the view.

`mapView.removeAnnotations(annotationsToRemove)` where `annotationsToRemove` is an array containing the specific annotations you need to remove.

Or, if you want to add all the annotations again, you can remove all the annotations with
`mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)`